# Handle a PL/SQL function returning a record in PHP

Tags: php, plsql, record

I've been looking on the Internet and I didn't find an answer so here I am.

I've a PL/SQL function returning a record :

```
create or replace package pck_test is
    TYPE coord_geo is record (coord_x float, coord_y float);
    function ArrondiGeo(coord_x float, coord_y float) return coord_geo;
end pck_test;
/

create or replace package body pck_test is
    FUNCTION ArrondiGeo(coord_x FLOAT,coord_y FLOAT) RETURN coord_geo
    IS
        temp_x FLOAT(24);
        temp_y FLOAT(24);
        rec_coord coord_geo;
    BEGIN
        temp_x := ROUND(coord_x,4)/5;
        temp_y := ROUND(coord_y,4)/5;

        temp_x := ROUND((temp_x*5),3);
        temp_y := ROUND((temp_y*5),3);

        rec_coord.coord_x := temp_x;
        rec_coord.coord_y := temp_y;

        RETURN rec_coord;
    END;
END pck_test;
/
```

And I want to use it in a PHP function but I don't really know how ...

I tried this but it doesn't work :

```
public function get_tronc($x,$y)
    {
        $q = oci_parse($this->_db, 'begin :r := pck_test.ArrondiGeo(:x,:y); end;');
        oci_bind_by_name($q, ':x', $x);
        oci_bind_by_name($q, ':y', $y);
        oci_bind_by_name($q, ':r', $r);
        oci_execute($q);

        return $r;
    }
```

The error is :

```
Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-06550: line 1, column 13: PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored in /users/info/il3/jboeglin/Bureau/BDD/site/models/userManager.php on line 77
```

So that's a self explaining error but I still can't figure how I can use it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a *named datatype*, you probably need to bind your parameter specifying the `SQLT_NTY` type:

```
    $r = oci_new_collection($this->db, 'COORD_GEO');
    oci_bind_by_name($q, ':r', $r, -1, SQLT_NTY);
    ...
    oci_execute($q);

    // do whatever you need with your data
    $data = $elem = $collection->getElem(1);

    // then discard it
    $r->free();
```

See the manual of [oci_bind_by_name](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php) for details.

---

For *plain* PL/SQL records, you're probably out of luck: according to [Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10646/oci03typ.htm#LNOCI16271) you can't use OCI to fetch a record. As of Oracle 11g:

> The following two types are internal to PL/SQL and cannot be returned as values by OCI:
>
> - Boolean, **`SQLT_BOL`**
> - Record, **`SQLT_REC`**

*If* this is correct (I'm not a regular PHP user), you will probably have to wrap your function at PL/SQ level:

- either, in a procedure with the required number of `OUT` parameters;
- or maybe, depending your needs, in a *table function*.

For sake of completeness, please note that [Oracle 12c + OCI8 2.0.7 remove the restriction that had previously not allowed to return a boolean value](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/entry/support_for_pl_sql_boolean).

Comment: I tried it but I got :

    Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): Unable to find collection property in /users/info/il3/jboeglin/Bureau/BDD/site/models/userManager.php on line 76 Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-01008: not all variables bound in /users/info/il3/jboeglin/Bureau/BDD/site/models/userManager.php on line 77

Comment: @Jérôme To use `SQLT_NTY` you need to initialize your variable as an [OCI-Collection](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.OCI-Collection.php). I've edited my answer (the best I can remember) to show you how to do that.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that, even if it's working with a procedure

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for you answer, I tried SQLT_NTY but it doesn't work probably because OCI can't return records like you said, ...
I'll try to look at a table function.

Edit : I finally used a PROCEDURE

```
create or replace package pck_test is

PROCEDURE ArrondiGeo(coord_x IN FLOAT,coord_y IN FLOAT,temp_x OUT FLOAT,temp_y OUT FLOAT);

end pck_test;
/

create or replace package body pck_test is
    PROCEDURE ArrondiGeo(coord_x IN FLOAT,coord_y IN FLOAT,temp_x OUT FLOAT,temp_y OUT FLOAT)
    IS
    BEGIN
        temp_x := ROUND(coord_x,4)/5;
        temp_y := ROUND(coord_y,4)/5;

        temp_x := ROUND((temp_x*5),3);
        temp_y := ROUND((temp_y*5),3);
    END;
END pck_test;
```

/

and this php function :

```
public function get_tronc($x,$y)
{
    $q = oci_parse($this->_db, 'begin pck_test.ArrondiGeo(:x,:y,:xm,:ym); end;');
    oci_bind_by_name($q, ':x', $x);
    oci_bind_by_name($q, ':y', $y);
    oci_bind_by_name($q, ':xm', $xm,40);
    oci_bind_by_name($q, ':ym', $ym,40);
    oci_execute($q);

    $r=array($xm,$ym);

    return $r;
}
```