# Need help calling an Oracle package function from PHP

Tags: php, oracle, plsql, stored-functions

I am provided a function as part of an Oracle package as below:

packageX.functionY(a_project VARCHAR2, a_centers OUT Strings, a_types OUT Strings, a_values OUT Int32s);

The only way I can currently run this on Toad is as below:

```
DECLARE  
  a_centers Strings; 
  a_types Strings; 
  a_values Int32s; 
  n INTEGER :=0 ; 
BEGIN 
  packageX.functionY('myproject', a_centers, a_types, a_values); 
  n := a_centers.count; 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Test Result for packageX.functionY'); 
  FOR i in 1..n LOOP 
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( a_centers(i)  || '   '   ||  a_types(i) || '   '  ||      TO_CHAR(a_values(i))); 
  END LOOP; 
END;
```

I don't know how I can read the DBMS_OUTPUT with PHP. I read that this is not a good practice anyway.
I read a lot of examples and Oracle documentation how to call package functions but none seem to help on my case. I 'sense' that the part of the problem is the OUT parameters of the function but I am not sure.

My question is two folds.

1) Is it really a bad idea to read DBMS_OUTPUT with PHP? If not how do I do it?

2) Is there a way to return the data directly without using the DBMS_OUTPUT that I can read with oci functions on php?

Comment: Can you create another function/ procedure/ view that calls this function and call that new object from PHP?  Or do you really need the PHP code to execute an anonymous PL/SQL block?

Comment: I don't have create/write privileges on the Oracle side. Due to the tight deadline I need to work with the current function as is. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have not used PHP with Oracle since a long time ago, but if I remember it well, to fetch back a collection using PHP with OCI, you need to [bind the output parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php) as [a collection](http://php.net/manual/en/class.OCI-Collection.php) of the right type. Something *like* that:

> ```
> $q = oci_parse($conn,"CALL packageX.functionY('myproject', :r, :s, :t)");
>
> $r = oci_new_collection($this->db, 'Strings');
> //                                  ^^^^^^^
> //                      not sure about that though
> oci_bind_by_name($q, ':r', $r, -1, SQLT_NTY);
> oci_bind_by_name(...)
> ...
> oci_execute($q);
>
> // do whatever you need with your data
> $data = $elem = $collection->getElem(1);
>
> // then discard it
> $r->free();
> ```
>
> <sup>Untested. Beware of typos -- and probably need some adjustments...</sup>

There was a [similar question a few days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27525948/handle-a-pl-sql-function-returning-a-record-in-php/27527287#27527287). Maybe that could help you too.